# Qt program exited with code 0x0000139

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to run a Qt project that used to be built with Windows XP 32 bit in a Windows 7 x64 machine.

I installed Qt and I am able to build the project. However, my Qt installation is not working yet.
When I try to debug, I receive the following error:

```
During startup program exited with code 0x0000139
```

And when I try to run without debug, I receive the following:

```
Starting program-path.exe
The program has unexpectedly finished
program-path.exe crashed
```

Is there any configuration I have to change in order to build in a x64 machine?
The new machine has Qt 5.4 and MinGW 32bit version 4.9.1, while the old machine had Qt  5.3 and MinGW 32bit version 4.8.2.

In the event logs, the following error is registered:

```
Faulting module name: Qt5Guid.dll, version: 5.4.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I might be some null pointer flaw ...

Comment: The code is just checked out from SVN, and it used to work in the old system. I replaced the main method by `cout << "Loaded" << endl;` and the issue persists.

Comment: Are you building 32 bit? It is behaving the same way on **another** Windows 7 x64 machine?

Comment: I'm building 32 bit indeed, but I don't have another W7 machine to test right now. The executable built in the XP machine does work in W7 though.

Comment: I installed Qt 5.3 with MinGW 4.8.2 in W7 and everything works as expected. The problem was thus in changing the compiler version. I will keep it to this version for now.